# How do i turn my dictionary values into columns in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary, key

I currently have a dictionary `dicts` that looks like this (snippet):

```
{'Axa':          w      x     y     z
0     9.597307   8.533429  43.4  Axa
6     0.000000   4.631714  32.0  Axa
17    0.662168   6.271585  37.7  Axa
..         ...        ...   ...        ...
171   4.023485   9.104185  28.2  Axa
172   0.846931   5.703871  38.8  Axa
174  20.063263   6.436114  27.7  Axa

[66 rows x 4 columns]}
{'Bxa':         w      x    y         z
1     0.454497   5.443401  43.6  Bxa
3     0.086371   4.869583  42.3  Bxa
4     2.264084   7.330367  36.6  Bxa
5     7.312782  12.418908  38.0  Bxa
8    10.935617   1.474324  43.5  Bxa

[29 rows x 4 columns]}
```

It is a dictionary with `keys = {Axa, Bxa, Cxa, Dxa}` and values would be the columns `w` to `z`.

`type(dicts)` gives

```
<class 'dict'>
<class 'dict'>
<class 'dict'>
<class 'dict'>
<class 'dict'>
<class 'dict'>
```

I would like to retrieve a dataframe that looks like this:

```
| w          |    x      |   w     |    z | 
| --------   | ----------| --------| -----|
0  9.597307  | 8.533429  |   43.4  |   Axa|
1  0.000000  |  4.631714 |   32.0  |  Axa |
2  0.662168  |  6.271585 |   37.7  |  Axa |
...
63  4.023485 |  9.104185 |  28.2   |   Axa|
64   0.846931|   5.703871|  38.8   |  Axa |
65  20.063263|   6.436114| 27.7    | Axa  |
67  0.454497 |   5.443401|   43.6  |   Bxa|
68  0.086371 |  4.869583 | 42.3    | Bxa  |
69  2.264084 |   7.330367|  36.6   | Bxa  |
```

I have tried this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(dicts.values()), columns = ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z'])
```

but I got this:

```
ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(1, 66, 4)
```

Usually we use the `key` as column name and `values` as column values but in this case I want my `values` to be both. How do I do this?

This is my full code:

```
for ph in data.model.unique():
    
    dicts = {}

    "This loop aims to extract outliers from the dataset using Gaussian mixture models for each phone model and create new df"
    data = data[data.model==ph]
    data = data[['r_var',  'b_var', 'SPAD', 'model']]
    data = data[['r_var', 'b_var']].values

    probs = gmm.score_samples(data)

    probs_mean, probs_sd = mean(probs), std(probs)
    cut_off = probs_sd * 2
    lower, upper = probs_mean - cut_off, probs_mean + cut_off
    not_outliers = data[probs > lower]

    # append to dicts
    dicts[ph] = not_outliers
    df = pd.concat(dicts).reset_index(drop=True)
    print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the values of the dict are dataframes, you can use `concat`:

```
df = pd.concat(list(dicts.values()),ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = pd.concat(dicts).reset_index(drop=True)
```

EDIT:

Your solution is necessry change with `dicts = {}` and also `concat` outside loops:

```
dicts = {}
for ph in data.model.unique():

    "This loop aims to extract outliers from the dataset using Gaussian mixture models for each phone model and create new df"
    data = data[data.model==ph]
    data = data[['r_var',  'b_var', 'SPAD', 'model']]
    data = data[['r_var', 'b_var']].values

    probs = gmm.score_samples(data)

    probs_mean, probs_sd = mean(probs), std(probs)
    cut_off = probs_sd * 2
    lower, upper = probs_mean - cut_off, probs_mean + cut_off
    not_outliers = dataf[probs > lower]

    # append to dicts
    dicts[ph] = not_outliers
    
df = pd.concat(dicts).reset_index(drop=True)
print(len(df))
```

Comment: Can I check will `df` also be a dictionary with many different dataframes? When I print `type(df)` it gives me


`<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`

`len(df)` also only gives me the number of rows for the last dataframe in `df`, instead of the total number of rows across all dataframes. 

How do I 'join' these different dataframes in `df` into just one single dataframe?

Comment: @user16285826 - `Can I check will df also be a dictionary with many different dataframes?` It is not joined all together to one big? If use `print (dicts['Axa'])` it not return one DataFrame for `Axa` ?

Comment: @user16285826 - Because it test with `dicts = {'Axa': pd.DataFrame({'w':[1,2], 'x':list('as')}), 'Bxa': pd.DataFrame({'w':[10,1], 'x':list('tr')})}` my solution working perfectly, if for you not, input data are different.